# Xcode > Debug > Storekit > Manage Transactions shows transaction status as purchased, but the state as unfinished?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, store, storekit

Code below. I'm calling SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction) after updatedTransactions is called - not sure why the transaction state would be unfinished in Xcode's Storekit Transactions.

```
    internal func purchaseFullVersion() {
        if let product = product {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased : purchased(transaction: transaction)
            case .failed : failed(transaction: transaction)
            case .restored : restored(transaction: transaction)
            default : break
            }
        }
    }

    internal func purchased(transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        print("Purchased")
        guard let product = product else { return }
        purchaseTransactionComplete() // this updates UserDefaults
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
extension PremiumScreen : SKPaymentTransactionObserver
{
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        ProgressViewHide(uiView: self.view)
        showAlertMsg(Message: "Subscription Restored Successfully!", AutoHide: false)
        Subscribe.save(true)
    }
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        ProgressViewHide(uiView: self.view)
    }
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        transactions.forEach({
            switch $0.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                print("purchasing")
            case .purchased:
                print("purchased")
                ProgressViewHide(uiView: self.view)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
                setHomeDashBoard()
            case .failed:
                print("failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
            case .restored:
                print("restored")
            case .deferred:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. Please edit your answer and explain what was wrong and how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi Piyush, your code is calling exactly the same method as mine (SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)), I just can't work out why in Xcode > Storekit, it says that the transaction is unfinished even though I called the finishTransaction() method.